# svg path d="⋯" three dots does not work in any browsers, so svg images do not show

Tags: svg, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I have a problem with svg image's path.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="225.65" height="46.59" >
   <defs></defs>
   <desc>ESSENTIALS</desc>
   <path fill="#477294" d="M52.6 25.36h8⋯2.33-2.33z" />
</svg>
```

currently I'm working on Gastby.js with a tutorial book and try to build a simple website.
the tutorial shows that above code for svg images and I wrote exactly the same, but it did not work at all on browsers.
What I tried was 1) not three dots(⋯), I wrote space between 8 and 2,   2) just ... three dots.

I would appreciate that if you could help me or any suggesion.

Thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: three dots are [an ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). It's used in text to indicate that the detail is not shown so as not to clutter the example.

Comment: There is extra code that has been omitted from the example and replaced with an ellipsis for brevity.

Comment: Oh, this question was supposed to be stupid.. but Thank you for your answers !!!! It worked!